# Does it make sense to spam the snackbar for information already available elsewhere?

Tags: material-design, google-materials-design, material

Does it make sense to spam the snackbar for information already available elsewhere? Let's say you have a console dishing out 10-30 lines per seconds and you want to put some of the information on a snackbar, so that you have a new message 0.5 to 1 second overriding the previous message with buttons that open various tabs inside the console panel. Does it make sense to do that? Why not? And do you have sources to support your argument?

There is 3 tabs inside the console panel and the console panel outputs a lot of information rapidly. The snackbar will output 10% of all the messages that are outputted inside the console panel. What would you do as a UX designer? To be honest, I don't think it makes any sense, but I had to argue with 2 of my colleagues over this, and they're not convince I am right, because I don't have UX documents to back up my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't want to overstep on your colleague and fellow designers, but by knowing only what you just told us, this is how I would analyse it.

As a UX designer, I would advise against spamming the snackbar with information that is already available elsewhere in the console panel. Here's why:

- **User experience POV**: A snackbar is meant to provide short and important notifications to the user. If the snackbar is constantly being updated with information that is already available in the console panel, it can be distracting and overwhelming for the user. It may also result in users missing important notifications.
- **Context switching principle**: If the snackbar contains buttons that open various tabs inside the console panel, it can lead to frequent context switching for the user. This can make it difficult for users to focus on the task at hand and can result in a less efficient workflow.
- **Information overload**: If the console panel outputs a lot of information rapidly, adding more information to the snackbar can contribute to information overload. This can make it difficult for users to process and prioritize information, which can impact their ability to make informed decisions.

Instead, as a UX designer, I would recommend consolidating the information in the console panel and presenting it in a way that is easily digestible for the user. (those 10%) This could include features such as filtering, sorting, and search capabilities, which can help users quickly find the information they need.

Additionally, consider providing contextual help or tooltips to guide users on how to use the console panel effectively. (unless your interface is for power users)

My recommendation is based on best practices in UX design, as well as principles of information design and human-computer interaction. I would recommend proposing that approach and conducting user research to validate the approach.

It's ok to try something based on guessing how the user will appreciate it, but it's important tout collect their feedback and act for the usability of the interface.

Hope this answer can help you.

Sources:

- https://www.creativejuiz.fr/blog/wp-content/uploads/2023/01/criteres-ergonomiques-pour-evaluation-interfaces-utilisateur-scapin-bastien-heuristics-ux-ui.pdf
- https://www.nngroup.com/articles/minimize-cognitive-load/
- https://www.educative.io/answers/what-are-snackbars-in-ui-design

Comment: I like the idea of filtering or summarising the messages - That adds much more value than simply echoing the console.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood you correctly, but I'll try to answer.

As I understand it, you work with the console, and you send requests to it and get a response. In addition, from time to time you receive messages that carry additional information.

I think you don't need to use the snackbar for this purpose. And I would include this information directly in the console.
Of course, I would make it more visually visible and understandable.

I hope I understood your question correctly, let me know if not.